# Error in ifelse unused argument(3) in a function in R programming

Tags: r

```
tod = function(x) { 
  ifelse(x > 5 && x < 12, 1, ifelse( x > 16 && x < 20, 2, 3), 3)
}
df2$day = tod(df2$t)
```

> Error in ifelse(x > 5 && x < 12, 1, ifelse(x > 16 && x < 20, 2, 3), 3): unused argument (3)

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting your `ifelse` calls incorrectly, but to avoid this completely you might want to look into using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
tod = function(x) {
    case_when(
        x > 5 && x < 12  ~ 1,
        x > 16 && x < 20 ~ 2,
        TRUE             ~ 3
    )
}
```

Comment: You could also use `between()` from `dplyr` _e.g._ `case_when(between(x, 6, 11) ~ 1, ...)` (assuming integer values of x)

Answer (score 0):

```
ifelse(x > 5 && x < 12, 1, ifelse( x > 16 && x < 20, 2, 3))
```

You first ifelse expects 3 arguments. 1st: `x > 5 && x < 12`
2nd: `1`
3rd: `ifelse( x > 16 && x < 20, 2, 3)`

With `, 3` you gave a 4th argument to your first `ifelse()`, which caused the error